# How can I use OAuth2, the Password Flow, and OTP?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openiddict

In my initial implementation of my app I used OpenIddict's `~/connect/token` action via the Password Flow to validate a users' username and password. When the username and password was right, the user would receieve a token with their scopes etc, as per the OAuth2 spec.

Now, I'm introducing One-time PIN to my app (OTP). If a user signs up with the app, but wants to *skip* OTP validation, they should be able to. But in doing so, they will not recieve their full list of scopes - they will just get the basic scopes until they validate their account. This is because a user could be scoped for admin access or something but shouldn't recieve that scope until we have validated their email address as being legitimate. Unvalidated clients should still be able to use the app to an extent, just not with their normal permissions (if they have any fancy permissions).

As far as I can tell, I can't modify the `OpenIdConnectRequest` to add in a OTP or something like that, so how can I use an OTP in an OAuth2 password flow, using OpenIddict?

(Also, if reading the above sounds like pure unmitigated insanity, and I'm introducing horrible security holes in my app so big you just want to howl at the moon, please tell me.)

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR : Switch to Authorization code grant and use OTP in front end, prior to requesting tokens**

I would advice you to migrate to [Authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) and avoid using resource owner credential grant. There are two reasons for this. First, OAuth 2.1 specification will remove the  resource owner credential grant ([source](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-1.9)). Further, as you have identified, OTP and token request combination does not go along.

Hence, best options would be to switch to Authorization code grant and use OTP in front end.

1. Request end user credentials
2. OTP step - can be skipped
3. Token request

Binding OTP skipped or provided state is up to the OpenIddict implementation.

Comment: Thanks Kavindu! I can't switch to Authorization code grant. I'm using Flutter for Web as part of my project and it can't accept the token via callback. But your answer is probably the right way to solve this so I've accpted it. Thanks 

Comment: @LewisCianci hmm, authorization code flow does not require you to accept tokens via call back. But it require you to accept a redirect and accept authorization code. I am sure there are solutions to handle this.